# Multiple updates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 500 records in Excel and it contains some columns which is same as the columns in SQL DB Table. I have old column value 
as well as new column value in excel.

Example

### Excel

```
Name Age OldEmployeeID NewEmployeeID

x    1    100          200
y    2    101          201  
z    3    102          202
```

SqlTable

### EmployeeTable

```
Name Age Department City EmployeeID
x    1     HR        x    100
a    4     HR        x    103
y    2     Admin     x    101
b    5     Finance   x    104
c    3     IT        x    102
```

I want to update EmployeeID column in SQL Table as NewEmployeeID which is there in excel. 
Can anyone suggest how to write a sql query to update the sql table.

Comment: Is `EmployeeID` an identity column?

Comment: not an identity column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column is not an ID Column or having some other constraint you can:

**Option 1:**

Assuming your table is similar to the screenshot you have a concatenated column with this formula and drag it down and copy it directly into SQL.

```
=CONCATENATE("UPDATE dbo.EmployeeTable SET EmployeeID = ",D2," WHERE EmployeeID = ",C2,";")
```

[image]

**Option 2:**

You can import the Excel file into SQL and use a statement like the one below.  However, be cautious if any of the old EmployeeIDs overlap the new EmployeeIDs. For Example if Jim has ID 100 and his new one is 500 and Jane's new ID is 100 and if you accidentally run it a second time, the Jane will also get an ID of 500.

```
UPDATE EmployeeTable SET EmployeeID = Excel.NewEmployeeID
FROM
    EmployeeTable
    JOIN ExcelTable
        ON  Excel.OldEmployeeID = EmployeeTable.EmployeeID
;
```

Comment: You can also specify multiple `ON` criteria to mitigate chances of overlap. by adding `AND` i.e. `ON Col1 = Col2 AND Col3 = Col4...`